# Hardware for positioning smartphone or tablet next to bed and using a hardware keyboard

Tags: smartphones, tablet, smart-device, tracking-devices

Can someone recommend a device for attaching a keyboard to a wheelchair and a device with a rotatable mechanical arm similar to a lampshade light for attaching to a bedside table, allowing you to position the phone or tablet anywhere, next to the bed, while using the keyboard on the bed (or, on the bedside table)?

Please migrate this post to the user experience stack exchange if more appropriate there.

This would be important for disabled users who need to use a hardware keyboard instead of a phone keyboard, even for programmers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a "keyboard arm". Arms that screw into a wall (or other veritcal surface), screw into a desk (horizontal surface), or clamp to a desk are common. Ones lik this [Vivo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BWSJLD92) that clamp to a pole are a bit more rare.

In indstry, they use combo monitor and keyboard arms like this [Ergotron](https://www.globalindustrial.com/p/ergotron-200-series-combo-arm-mounting-kit-black), and this may fit a bedriden person very well, but they are on the expensive side of the spectrum.